# How to run powerful analyses with non-normal data

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, linear-model, nonparametric

I coded the amount of speech that participants used during several tasks and I want to use this information to predict performance on other tasks. I also want to test whether speech on one task is related to speech on another. Specifically, I coded whether or not speech was used on a given trial of a task, and calculated a percentage (i.e., percent of trials on which participant used X speech).

All of my data are non-normal, primarily because there were a lot of participants who didn't use any speech on any trials, and there were also many who used speech on all trials.

What is the most straightforward way to deal with these data? I could use non-parametric correlations for some analyses, but in some cases I'll want to use something equivalent to linear regression (with the speech variable as a predictor, among other predictors). Attached are some histograms of the data.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

First, OLS regression makes no assumptions about the distribution of the *data* it makes assumptions about the distribution of the *error* which is estimated by the residuals.

Second, there are a lot of regression type models that do not make these assumptions: Quantile regression, various robust regression methods, regression trees and their offspring and more.